# Duplicate Rules appearing on MVC Home Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have been following a article on [Visual Studio Magazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2014/03/14/ASP-dotNET-Extensibility-with-MEF.aspx?Page=2) and have found that for some reason I am getting duplicates for Rules in the drop down on my page. Could someone please explain what I am missing here? Also I would like to know how I could fix this issue.

Upon closer inspection I believe the issue lies with the Validators line as it appears to be reading in 4 objects rather than 2 (a Phone validator and an Email validator). The Email validator code is essentially the same as the Phone but using a different regex.

Controller code:

```
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<Lazy<BusinessRules.IValidate<string>, BusinessRules.IValidateMetaData>> Validators { get; private set; }

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new ValidationFormModel();
    vm.Rules = new List<SelectListItem>(from v in Validators
                                        select new SelectListItem() 
                                        { Text = v.Metadata.Name, 
                                            Value = v.Metadata.Name });

    return View(vm);
}
```

View Model code:

```
public class ValidationFormModel
{
    public string Input { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Rules { get; set; }
    public string Rule { get; set; }
    public string StatusLabel { get; set; }
}
```

Business Rules Code

```
[Export(typeof(IValidate<string>))]
[ExportMetadata("Name", "Phone")]
public class ValidatePhone : IValidate<string>
{
    const string PHONE_PATTERN = @"^((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}$";

    public ValidationResult Validate(string input)
    {
        var result = new ValidationResult();

        if (input == null || !Regex.IsMatch(input, PHONE_PATTERN))
        {
            result.ErrorMessage = string.Format("{0} is not a valid phone number");
        }
        else
        {
            result.IsValid = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The View:

```
@model ValidationExample.ViewModels.ValidationFormModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MEF Demo";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <strong>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StatusLabel)</strong>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Validation Demo</legend>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Input)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Input)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Rule)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Rule, Model.Rules)
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" />

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has not been answered and I no longer care about the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the view, try using `IEnumerable`

`@model IEnumerable<ValidationExample.ViewModels.ValidationFormModel>`

and try changing your dropdown list to a normal `<select>`

`<fieldset>
        <legend>Validation Demo</legend>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Input)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Input)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Rule)`

```
    foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <select>@item.Rule </select>
    }
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I will try this. But why is the duplicates occurring in the first place? You haven't really explained what the cause was.

Comment: Tried this and it failed, 
Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ValidationExample.ViewModels.ValidationFormModel>' does not contain a definition for 'StatusLabel' and no extension method 'StatusLabel' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ValidationExample.ViewModels.ValidationFormModel>' could be found

Comment: I have updated my question with the area which I believe is causing the issue (The Validator object in the controller)